# Create Session in Rails 3.1 Hartl Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

This question is admittedly long. So I appreciate any support from the rubytutorial community. I am in Chapter 9, attempting to create a session for a logged-in user.

I've done the tutorial already in < Rails 3.1. Since I am now using Rails 3.1, I headed on over to Chapter 13 and linked to the (very good) [Railscasts (#270) on the subject](http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1). I was able to rewrite my user sign up pretty easily thanks to has_secure_password.

When I try to log in with a user in the database I see this in the console):

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
```

Seems like I need to create a route and it should work. But if that is the case, why can I go 'users/1' and the view appear? I am using the route user_path(@user), @user in my sessions and users controllers (below).

Here is what I did.

Pass a form to the Session controller new action (note: I use form_tag and not form_for)

```
    <%= form_tag sessions_path do %>

    <div class="field">
        <%= label_tag :email %><br />
        <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email] %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <%= label_tag :password %><br />
        <%= password_field_tag :password %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
        <%= submit_tag "Sign In" %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

Then, create action in sessions_controller.rb

```
def create
#Assign object by email attribute
user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
# User is present and has access, must be true otherwise nil object
if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    RIGHT HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    redirect_to user_path(@user), :notice => "Logged in!"
else
    #Use flash.now on render not flash[]
    flash.now.alert = "Invalid email or password"
    render "new"
end
end
```

And finally Create action for users_controller.rb, which works fine.

```
def create
 @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
        flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
        redirect_to @user
    else
        render "new"
        @user.password.clear
        @user.password_confirmation.clear
    end
end
```

Leaving my User model:

```
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

has_secure_password
```

Oh and here is my current routes.rb file

```
 resources :users
 resources :sessions, only: [:create, :new, :destroy]

 root to: "pages#home"
 match "/about",        to: "pages#about"
 match "/contact", to: "pages#contact"
 match "/help",         to: "pages#help"
 match "/signup",   to: "users#new" 
 match "/signin",   to: "sessions#new"
 match "/signout",  to: "sessions#destroy"
```

And finally my output when I run rake routes:

```
users GET    /users(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"users"}
POST   /users(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"users"}
new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}
edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"users"}
user GET    /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
PUT    /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"users"}
DELETE /users/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"users"}
sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"sessions"}
new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)   {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions"}
session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)   {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"sessions"}
root        /                         {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"home"}
about        /about(.:format)          {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"about"}
contact        /contact(.:format)        {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"contact"}
help        /help(.:format)           {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"help"}
signup        /signup(.:format)         {:controller=>"users", :action=>"new"}
signin        /signin(.:format)         {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"new"}
signout        /signout(.:format)        {:controller=>"sessions", :action=>"destroy"}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's your `redirect_to @user` and/or user_path(@user) lines. They generate requests to /users/:id, which apparently isn't in your routes.rb.

Comment: Thank you, I did not think of that. Because I can type the URI users/:id and can view the route in my browser. Yet it is not in my routes.rb. How should this appear in my route file. I've added my rake routes output and my routes.rb file.

Answer (score 0):

`@user` is nil in your example - you're assigning to user. What rails is telling you in a not very helpful way is that it can't route to `:controller => 'users', :action => 'show'` without a user.